# Accessing attributes of an stdClass PHP

Tags: php, json

I am making a request to Google's reverse GeoCode system and they return a large JSON object which I can't seem to access the attributes. The response looks something like this:

```
{
    "results" : [
        "address_components" : [
             {
                 "long_name" : "123",
                 "short_name" : "123",
                 "types" : [ "street_number" ]
             },
             { 
                 etc.
             }
         ],
        "formatted_address" : "123 Broadway, New York City, NY 10002, USA"
    ]
}
```

When it has been decoded it looks like this:

```
stdClass Object ( 
     [results] => Array ( 
         [0] => stdClass Object (  
             [address_components] => Array ( 
                 [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                     [long_name] => 123 
                     [short_name] => 123 
                     [types] => Array ( [0] => street_number ) 
                 )
             )
         ) 
         [formatted_address] => 123 Broadway, New York City, NY 10002, USA
     )
 )
```

How do I go about accessing the [formatted_address] attribute? I tried `$geoCode->["results"]->formatted_address` but that returns no value. I am stumped here, thanks!

Comment: Psst, if you pass a `true` as the second argument to `json_decode`, you get a multidimensional array instead of a set of nested stdClasses.  Nested arrays are a great deal easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$geoCode->results[0]->formatted_address
```