# PHP Split string from api reference

Tags: php, arrays, gocardless

I am using the GoCardless API to get a customers bank account name and last two digits of their account number.

I have followed their guide and pulling back the deatails:

Code

```
  'access_token' => 'XXXXX-XXXXX',
  'environment'  => \GoCardlessPro\Environment::LIVE
));

$BankName=$client->customerBankAccounts()->get("BA000Q7C01AP71");
```

printing `$BankName` shows me something similar to the below:

```
CustomerBankAccount Class stdClass Object ( [id] => BA000Q7C01AP60 [created_at] => 2020-01-21T20:56:53.381Z [account_number_ending] => 11 [account_holder_name] => S TEST [account_type] => [bank_name] => HSBC BANK LIMITED [currency] => GBP [country_code] => GB [metadata] => stdClass Object ( ) [enabled] => 1 [links] => stdClass Object ( [customer] => CU000QFVZRF7 ) )
```

How do i split this string, as i only want `[bank_name]` and `[account_number_ending]`

[GoCardless Reference](https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#customer-bank-accounts-get-a-single-customer-bank-account)

Comment: it is not a string, but an object, so you can access its attribute with the `->` operator, e.g. `$bankName->account_number_ending;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing attributes of an stdClass PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785341/accessing-attributes-of-an-stdclass-php)

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz Thanks, so how would i 'echo' just the account_number_ending?

Comment: `echo $bankName->account_number_ending;`

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz - that shows absolutely nothing...

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz - Ahh capital B! Thank you :)